# Cocos2d not dealloc-ing the scene (again)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, release, dealloc

this is my first post so don't go too rough on me.

I have a problem with cocos2d. Im making a game with a HUD layer and a game layer. When I call replace main menu scene with [ClassicGameLayer scene] my HUD and game layer get init-ed this way:

```
+ (CCScene*)scene
{
CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

HudLayer *hud = [[[HudLayer alloc] initWithMode:1] autorelease];
ClassicGameLayer *layer = [[[ClassicGameLayer alloc] initWithHUD:hud] autorelease];

[scene addChild:hud z:hudZ];
[scene addChild:layer z:layerZ];

return scene;
}
```

and when the user fails the game HUD layer calls

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameOverLayer sceneWithMode:integer andScore:points]]];
```

dealloc of the HUD layer gets called but dealloc of the ClassicGameLayer is never called. I googled almost everything I could think of but still no luck.
Does anybody know whats causing me this problem? And if so how can I fix it? Every other scene is being released properly i think :)

Comment: why do you care if dealloc is called?  You are using autorelease on both of them, so its up to the system to decided when to garbage collect it

Comment: Cause they seem to be causing memory issues. Game crashes after playing it for some time. I think that memory management is causing this problem.

Comment: if you are concerned with the memory management explicitly, then dont use autorelease. Just use manual retain/release and release the object your self when you are done with it.

Comment: You can run a NSLog in "applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning" then you'll know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your autorelease pool never gets to the place where it deallocates stuff, it will never release any memory. I had this issue once with a Mac app I was writing. It won't show up as a memory leak in Instruments, either.

I recommend not using autorelease if you are having this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only question not left is how?
If I change to just `[[ClassicGameLayer alloc] initWithHUD:hud]` how am I supposed to release it?
HUD replaces the scene so my classic game layer "doesn't know" when its getting replaced. Should I override `- (void)onExit` method?

Comment: I can't really answer this without seeing how the program is structured.